# Python logging: configure individual logger with dictionary

Tags: python, logging

Using Python's `logging` module, I want to configure two separate loggers. One for dev and one for ops.
I can do this using configuration methods like `addHandler` (see code at the bottom of question), but I don't see a way to do it with a config dictionary. Instead the dictConfig seems reserved for the whole logging module. How would I configure a named `logger` using a dictionary?

This is the code I use to configure two loggers, `ops` and `dev` using method calls, nothing special there, just to give a sense of the functionality that I want:

```
import logging

# create logger
ops_logger = logging.getLogger('ops')
dev_logger = logging.getLogger('dev')
ops_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
dev_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ops_file = logging.FileHandler("ops")
dev_file = logging.FileHandler("dev")
ops_file.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
dev_file.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to ch
ops_file.setFormatter(formatter)
dev_file.setFormatter(formatter)
# add ch to logger
ops_logger.addHandler(ops_file)
dev_logger.addHandler(dev_file)
# 'application' code


ops_logger.error('ops error message')
dev_logger.error('dev error message')
```

I'm using 2.7, but will accept 3.x solutions otherwise

Comment: Did you achieve what you look for ?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore. I changed companies since posting this question so I don't have access to the code I wrote anymore :/